# Software Design Pattern for resource libraries?

Tags: delphi, resources

Is there any pattern (software design pattern) for loading images or message strings from resource files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pattern describes a general solution to a particular situation. It's about the larger structure and not about single commands.

Loading images or message strings from resource files boils down to simple commands, i.e.

```
LoadString (HINSTANCE, UINT, LPTSTR, int)
```

so I don't think that you will find a "pattern" for this.

Comment: Think of a larger project with multi language support.

Comment: Pavan, no matter the size of a project, the "pattern" for loading things from resource files is always going to be "load the resource." You can pile other abstractions on top of it, but those don't change the pattern. Clearly, a pattern isn't really what you're looking for. Maybe you're asking about "best practices" or "idioms."

Answer (score 1):

**1. Text resources**

To use text resources, the more simple is to implement resourcestring to store your text:

```
resourcestring
  sMsgHello = 'Hello world';

begin
  ShowMessage(sMsgHello); // will be loaded from resource
end;
```

Think as sMsgHello as a constant loaded from the resource. By default, it will contain the text written in the code.

If the text was not define in the source code, you can call the LoadResString() Delphi function or the LoadString() API.

**2. Other resources**

For not text resources, the most simple is to use TResourceStream:

```
var 
  RS: TStream;
  s: string;
begin
  RS := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance,'ResName','TXT');
  try
    SetString(s,PChar(RS.Memory),RS.Size);
    Memo.Text := s;
  finally
    RS.Free;  
  end;
end;
```

Resources can be very powerful. You can [find here](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=232#p232) how you could embed a ZIP as a resource, then read any internal compressed file when needed. Resources are memory-mapped within the exe so they are loaded in memory only on request. You can have a huge exe with a lot of resources inside, which still loads immediately: resources are read from disk only when necessary.